# How to set Ionic's LocalStorage as synchronization?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Here's what I want: When I send a net request, hoping the `intercept` can add `headers` automatically.

So I made an  `intercept` to realize the goal. I plan to get value by `LocalStorage`. Howerer the way of it's executive is asynchronous, so the request can't catch up with the `storage`.

What should I do next?

My code as belows:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
   Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>> {
    console.log('into intercept');
    let url = req.url;
    let opuser;
    this.storage.get('userInfo').then((val) => {
        opuser = val.Noid; // get the value what I need
    });

    if (opuser === undefined) {
        opuser = 'undefined';
    }
    const newReq = req.clone({
        url: url
    }).clone({
        setHeaders: { opuser: 'undefined' }
    });// set the headers
    return next.handle(newReq).pipe(
        mergeMap((event: any) => {
            return of(event);
        })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prepare your **header** before the interceptor will be called.

**Good option:**

When your application starts, get the **header** and store it in a provider. This way you will have synchronous/direct access to it.

```
opUserHeader: any;

setOpuserHeader(){
   return this.storage.get('userInfo').then((val) => {
      this.opUserHeader = val.Noid; // get the value what I need
   });
}

getOpuserHeader(){
   return this.opUserHeader ? this.opUserHeader : 'undefined';
}
```

and when you start the app, you can call the method from your service in **app.component.ts** or in the first page(your choice), and your header value will exist in memory:

```
headersService.setOpuserHeader().then(() => { console.log('Header is set')};
```

now the **interceptor** should look very clean and you can directly get the value:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Get the header from service, attach to the cloned request and continue
    const opUserHeader = this.headersService.getOpuserHeader();
    const authReq = req.clone({setHeaders: {opuser: opUserHeader}});
    return next.handle(authReq);

}
```

**Bad Option:**

You can put your existing code in the localStorage promise and get the value from it for all requests but performance will be affected.

**Edit for Part 2:**

You don't really need the address inside the interceptor function but you should call the **POST** method with the correct qualifier.

A complex option can be to override the HttpClient and concatenate your address to all the methods(if you don't change the endpoint) or the easiest and most sustainable in your case would be to save the address in a service and require it everytime you need like so:

```
apiURL = 'http://120.XXX.XXX.XXX:81/';

getApiURL(){
     return this.apiURL;
}
```

and everytime you call the HttpClient:

```
const apiURL = myService.getApiURL();
this.httpClient.post(apiURL + 'api/login', params);
```

Good luck!